# Issue with Access-Control-Allow-Origin on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cors

I have a php file that is sitting on a web server that has the following code to allow it to be accessed from other domains:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
```

When I make a request from my test server(s) I get the response on Chrome Dev Tools

```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://beta.dean.technology/proxy.php. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

An example request I have made is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4N4wg/)

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://beta.dean.technology/proxy.php',type:"POST",data: '{}',contentType:"application/json",dataType:"json"})
```

I have also used online HTTP header inspectors and they are replying with "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***". I have also placed this file on different servers and still the same results. The file can be accessed by going to the url normally.

Has anyone got any ideas on this issue.

**EDIT 1:** 
PHP Source File
http://beta.dean.technology/proxySource.txt

Comment: I've been working quite a bit with CORS recently, encountering all sorts of problems with pre-flight requests such as this. I'd recommend looking at [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) as this helped me hugely with my development.

Comment: My code acts like a proxy to combat this issue which worked great, until I placed it onto the deployment server. Its used to POST data and GET the results. Unfortunately JSONP doesn't support POST

Comment: Do you have a source stating that JSONP doesn't support POST? I'm using AJAX `$.post` requests using JSONP no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you emit the headers on the OPTIONS pre-flight request. You don't need to emit it on GET or POST requests, you're allowed to emit them but it doesn't do anything.

Before the actual POST request is made your browser will issue a pre-flight request that is an OPTIONS request.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "OPTIONS") {
    // emit CORS headers
    exit;
} else {
    // regular request
}
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with the issue, only omitting the headers when a 'user' accesses the page. I want the page accessible at all time, to all devices/methods.

Comment: That is inconsequential. My point is: verify that the headers are emitted on the `OPTIONS` request because that error message seems to indicate that they aren't: _No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ..._

Comment: Sorry to jump the gun. I have used your code and see that on the Options Request, it doesn't reply the Access-Control-Allow-Origin but does reply with http://pastebin.com/z89Up5K4

Comment: See if you can figure out what is handling the OPTIONS request. I'm not familiar enough with IIS to tell if you it does something with the OPTIONS request. Make sure it's handled to your PHP script.